# Too many redirects when checking req.isAuthenticated

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, passport.js

My code was somehow causing a redirect loop.  Users visiting `/account` should be redirected to `/login` if they aren't authenticated, and vice-versa.

I'm using `ensureAuth` as middleware to check that a user is logged in.  It seems to be receiving the request object (`req`), but there's no `req.user` object and `isAuthenticated()` always returns false.  Yet in the `/login` route, the same `isAuthenticated()` method returns *true* if the user is logged in.  This is the source of the redirect loop.

---

routes.js

```
var ensureAuth = function(req,res,next){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { // This always comes out false, even if the user is logged in!
    next();
  } else {
    req.flash('warning', 'You have to log in to do that.  ');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};

router.route('/account').get( ensureAuth, function(req,res){
  res.render('account.html');
})
```

auth.js

```
app.route('/login').get( function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('/account'); }
  else { res.render('login.html'); }
})
```

main.js

```
// Routes
app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use('/', require('./config/routes.js') );

// Auth
require('./config/passport.js')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/auth.js')(app, passport);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help others who are running into problems where `req.isAuthenticated()` always returns false, or `req.user` is always empty.

Basically, in order to have access to the authenticated session, I just needed to call `routes.js` *after* `app.use(passport.session())`.

```
// Auth
require('./config/passport.js')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/auth.js')(app, passport);

// Routes
app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use('/', require('./config/routes.js') );
```